# Send all fields values to server with bootstrap-table editable plugin

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table with x-editabel plugin. The table has 3 fields but only one is editable. I need to send to the server script all the fields and not only the editable field. The code I use is the following:

```
$('#table-result').bootstrapTable({
 columns: [
    [{
       field: 'Network Domain',
       title: 'Network domain'
      }, {
       field: 'Service Provider',
       title: 'Service provider'
      }, {
       field: 'Category',
       title: 'Category',
       editable: {
         url: ajaxurl,
         ajaxOptions: {
           type: 'get',
           dataType: 'json'
         },
         success: function(response, newValue) {
          /* some code here */
         },
         type: 'select',
         title: 'Select category',
         placement: 'left',
         emptytext: 'empty text',
         source: [
            {value: 'cat1', text: 'cat1'},
            {value: 'cat2', text: 'cat2'}
         ]
      }],
});
```

And this the HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
    id="table-result"
    data-height="800"
    data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-page-number="1"
    data-page-size="10"
    data-search="false"
    data-side-pagination="client"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-show-export="true"
    data-sort-name="Category"
    data-sort-order="desc"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar"
    >
</table>
```

Table data comes from ajax (no problem: it's working).

I need to send all the fields, and not only the category field, to the ajax script which will perform the changes to the selected category field . I cannot define and use a pk for each table row because the action I need to do when I click on the editable field needs all the fields.
I thought to use the 'params' options of x-editable but I don't know how to tell it the current values of the row I am editing.

Do you have any suggestion?
TIA

P.S.
Sorry if I cannot explain the question in an "understandable" form but English is not my primary language.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I solved the problem.

Removed the ajax part from editable:

```
{
  url: ajaxurl,
  ajaxOptions: {
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json'
},
success: function(response, newValue) {
   /* some code here */
},
```

and added as event later on the code:

```
$('#table-result').on('editable-save.bs.table', function(e, field, row, oldValue, $el){
    //row.oldCategory = oldValue;
    //console.log(row);
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            'action': 'update',
            'Network Domain': row["Network Domain"],
            'Service Provider': row["Service Provider"],
            'Category': row["Category"],
            'oldCategory': oldValue
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '$ajax_action_url'
    }).done(function(response) {
        // If successful
       console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // If fail
        console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    });  
});
```